# Getting An Exception When Compiling The Win32 Console Project In My Code With Unicode (C++ Mingw64 VSCODE)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I am using `mingw64` compiler with VSCode. I wrote some code following a tutorial to print something to the console using `<Windows.h>`. I then modified my code to work with UNICODE characters. I have used `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter*( )` to do so. But I get a runtime exception when I run the program.
Segmentation Fault in VSCode. Please let me know if there's an error in my code.

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

const short screenWidth = 80, screenHeight = 80;
const wchar_t* consoleTitle = L"My Console Window";

int main()
{
    HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SMALL_RECT windowArea = { 0, 0, screenWidth - 1, screenHeight - 1 };
    COORD windowSize = { screenWidth, screenHeight };

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hOut, TRUE, &windowArea);
    SetConsoleTitle(consoleTitle);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hOut);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hOut, windowSize);

    wchar_t* screenBuffer = new wchar_t[screenWidth * screenHeight];

    for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
        {
            screenBuffer[y * screenWidth + x] = L' ';
        }
    }

    LPDWORD numberOfCharsWritten = 0;

    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, screenBuffer, screenWidth * screenHeight, { 0, 0 }, numberOfCharsWritten);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare DWORD variable not LPDWORD, and pass the variable's memory.

```
DWORD numberOfCharsWritten = 0;

WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, screenBuffer, screenWidth * screenHeight, { 0, 0 }, &numberOfCharsWritten);
```